# Writing NSMutableArrray to file an then reading it

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsmutablearray

I have a NSMutableArray feed.leagues which has two objects of `<MLBLeagueStandings: 0xeb2e4b0>`
I want to write it to  a file and then read it from the file. This is what I have done:

```
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder {
    [encoder encodeObject:feed.leagues forKey:@"feed.leagues"];
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.feed.leagues = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"feed.leagues"];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)saveJSONToCache:(NSMutableArray*)leaguesArray {
    NSString *cachePath = [self cacheJSONPath];

    [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:feed.leagues toFile:cachePath];
    NSMutableArray *aArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:cachePath];
    NSLog(@"aArray is %@", aArray);
}

-(NSString*)cacheJSONPath
{

   NSString *documentsDirStandings = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
   NSString *cacheJSONPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@_Standings.plist",documentsDirStandings, sport.acronym];
return cacheJSONPath;
}
```

Comment: Please specify what problems do you face?? And be specific what exactly you want to do.

Comment: I get this error                                                        2012-10-22 11:44:13.361 FOX Sports[60958:16d03] -[MLBLeagueStandings encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xee3d6c0
2012-10-22 11:44:13.362 FOX Sports[60958:16d03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MLBLeagueStandings encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xee3d6c0'
*** First throw call stack:                                                  at line [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:feed.leagues toFile:cachePath]

Comment: @Goti: I want to store feed.leagues array to a file and then read it from there in future. The array holds two MLBLeagueStandings class objects

Comment: Have you properly initialized feed.leagues array?? I think you are missing something to initialize. Some object you use is deallocated means the object is already released and you use it again.

Comment: feed.leagues is initialized properly as I get the value for feed.leagues if I debug the code.

Comment: I don't seem anything else dude..If I found anything, will get to you....one more thing always write `self` before. That is, in `feed.leagues`, put `self` like `self.feed.leagues`. Sometimes this also solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your object : MLBLeagueStandings should be serializable and respond to NSCoding protocole :

```
@interface MLBLeagueStandings : NSObject <NSCoding>{

}
```

Now in your MLBLeagueStandings class file (.m) add the following methods :

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder;
{
  self = [super initWithCoder:decoder];
  if(self)
  {
    yourAttribute = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"MY_KEY"]
    //do this for all your attributes
  }
}

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder;
{
  [encoder encodeObject:yourAttribute forKey:@"MY_KEY"];
  //do this for all your attributes
}
```

In fact if you want to write an object to a file (in your case it's an array), all the object contained in this array have to conform to the NSCoding protocole.

Moreover if you want example : [here is a good tutorial](http://benreimers.net.au/blog/saving-and-loading-data-nscoding-and-nskeyedarchiver)

Hope it will help you.

NB : if you want to encode/decode primitive type (int, float etc...) use :

```
[encode encodeInt:intValue forKey:@"KEY"];
```

([more information on apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCoder_Class/Reference/NSCoder.html))

Comment: how do I add object to encodeObject or decodeObjectforKey if its an int or float.

Comment: You can use [encoder encodeInt:intValue forKey:@"MY_INT_KEY"]; more information on apple documentation : https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCoder_Class/Reference/NSCoder.html